# How can I use transaction builder in Safe Wallet to deposit/withdraw, etc. with DeFi protocols, such as Pendle

Tags: gnosis-safe

May I know if it's possible to use the transaction builder dApp in Safe Wallet to interact with DeFi protocols, like deposit, borrow, buy, sell, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page.

Hope it helps; best, Louis